# Syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>

Tags: ruby

Trying to run code that contains the following lines:

```
tab=Hash.new
pta = alpha[1]
toto = alpha[2]
tab={pta.hex, toto.hex}
```

And I got this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
 tab={pta.hex, pta.hex}
```

I don't think it's a space error.

Comment: I will simply suggest you to read `Hash` & `Array` first because question shows you do not know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this piece of code

```
tab=Hash.new
pta = alpha[1]
toto = alpha[2]
tab={pta.hex, toto.hex}
```

If you want an array with the elements `pta.hex` and `toto.hex`, use this:

```
my_array = ["fofo" => pta , "toto" => toto]
```

Comment: @Ratata: "it doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Im trying to have an array with the elements pta.hex and toto.hex

Comment: @Gabbar yes it finally it was the first solution you proposed `my_array = ["fofo" => pta , "toto" => toto]`

Comment: @Ratata - If the previous answer worked, feel free to ask the author to update their answer (It's likely submitting an edit like that will get rejected in the "Review" queue :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you are not forming your hash correctly. So you have two options:

- Go for a **Hash**:

  `tab = { key1: pta.hex, key2: toto.hex }`
- Seems that you're trying to build an **Array**:

  `tab = [pta.hex, toto.hex]`